# bug javascript with chrome 22

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Since the upgrade of **Chrome 22** (stable release the 25th of september) I have discovered a new bug in my program that I don't understand.

My javascript program does the following :

1. Get a binary file (STL mesh) as a `arraybuffer` using an asynchrone `XMLHttpRequest`.
2. When a file is loaded parse it using `DataView` and calls to the reading methods such as `data.getFloat32(offset, isLittleEndian)` and `data.getUint32(offset, isLittleEndian)`. The parse data is stored in an array of the object that was used to load and parse the file.
3. I implemented a barriere to be sure to wait for all files to be loaded before continuing
4. When all files are loaded I go through each loader and create objects in a for loop using the data parsed and stored in an array as show below :

   ```
   var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
   for(var v = 0; v < this.result[0].length; v++) {
       geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(this.result[0][v][0],
                                                             this.result[0][v][1],
                                                             this.result[0][v][2])));
   }

   for(var f = 0; f < this.result[1].length; f++) {
       geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(this.result[1][f][0],
                                       this.result[1][f][1],
                                       this.result[1][f][2]));
   }
   ```
5. The problem is that after these loops the array `geom.faces` is `undefined`

I found a way to correct this comportement but I did not understand why it changes anything : I store the length of the arrays in variables as shown here :

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
var vl = this.result[0].length; // <===  | these are the added variables
var fl = this.result[1].length; // <===  | that fix the bug
for(var v = 0; v < vl; v++) {
    geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(this.result[0][v][0],
                                                          this.result[0][v][1],
                                                          this.result[0][v][2])));
}

for(var f = 0; f < fl; f++) {
    geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(this.result[1][f][0],
                                    this.result[1][f][1],
                                    this.result[1][f][2]));
}
```

If anyone could explain to me what happens and why I lose my array in the first version of my code that would be very appreciated.